# Date get using moment.unix() does not take the wanted format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have a millisecond value, `1519347000`, which was transformed using `moment.unix(1519347000)`.

I want to print it like `Feb 23, 2018 00:50` so I used inside the interpolation this format:

`{{obj.myDate| date:'MMM d, y hh:mm'}}` but the result looks like this:

```
Fri Feb 23 2018 00:50:00 GMT+0200
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: `moment.unix` returns an object (check in console what it looks like) with `.toString()` value of `Fri Feb 23 2018 00:50:00 GMT+0200`. AngularJS doesn't see it as a valid date object (just a string) and can't parse it correctly. All you need is `{{1519347000  * 1000 | date : 'MMM d, y hh:mm'}}`

Comment: Even if you have one momentjs object, you can call `toDate` on it to convert it to corresponding date object. Read about this [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/).

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I tried initially to do it like that. I have a column of values in a table which are sortable, but the problem is that the sorting is not working well. I've read that the JavaScript dates are not safe so that's why I tried using moment. Could it be a better solution than these two?

Comment: @LeoMessi yes, try ignoring angularjs formatting and use moment.js instead: you would need `{{obj.myDate}}` and `obj.myDate = moment.unix(1519347000).format('MMM d, YYYY hh:mm')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case at least, the solution was this:

`obj.myDate = moment.unix(1519347000).toDate());` in js file

`{{obj.myDate | date:'MMM d, y hh:mm'}}` in html